# Insert into table where column value is from a union statement

Tags: sql, insert, union

I have a union statement:

```
SELECT MAX(col + 1) FROM
(SELECT col FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT col FROM table_2) AS alias
```

I want to include this statement as part of an insert i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) VALUES(x, y, (the union statement), z)
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the additional columns (x,y) also in your select query. If the x,y are static values then you can directly add that values, otherwise you can change your query to include the additional x,y columns.

```
INSERT INTO table(col_1, col_2, col_3)
SELECT x, y,MAX(col + 1) ,z
FROM    (SELECT col FROM table_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT col FROM table_2
    ) AS alias
```

Comment: @Kurtiss, what is x,y,z here. Static values, variables or other output of another query?

Comment: The x,y,z are there just as examples, they could refer to anything; my main focus is how to insert the result of a union statement..

Comment: P.S. a column was missing from the statement for the insert to make sense i.e. col_4

Comment: @Kurtiss, to insert a query result to a table either you have mention all these columns in  that query - INSERT INTO table(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) SELECT x, y,MAX(col + 1) ,z ...  , or you have to specify the column - INSERT INTO table( col_3)  (the union statement)

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the scripts which you have given and it worked.

```
INSERT INTO table(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) VALUES(x, y, (SELECT MAX(col +1) FROM
    (SELECT col FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col FROM table_2) AS alias), z)
```

Do you have any errors which come when you put this simple statement ??

Comment: Was my first attempt, says it could not execute the statement due to the name given (i.e. col) being illegal in this context..

Comment: I did not get this error... you might want to give that a second try.

Comment: I just did, still didn't like it T-T